# SQl SET DATEFIRST when using DATENAME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> When the date parameter has a date data type argument, the return
>   value depends on the setting specified by using SET DATEFIRST.
>   [From DateName MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

If I am trying

`DateName(dw,getdate()) = 'sunday'`

do I need to worry about setting the DATEFIRST? I don't think I have to because I am not using the integer return, I am checking the Name of the day of the week that it was. Is this correct?

Comment: @andomar nice nonconstructive statement without any test code or evidence to back it up.

Comment: You're worried about `DATEFIRST` and completely ignoring `LANGUAGE`? Why would you care about one of those and not the other?

Comment: I can't imagine why it would affect it - today is always going Wednesday (until tomorrow anyway).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If the coalation is set to latin do you i still need to worry about Language?

Comment: I guess vote to close since it is not a good question

Comment: `set language french
select DATENAME(dw,getdate())` - `mercredi` - the language setting and the collation are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unasked question I think is - what's a reliable way to find a sunday.

I usually compare with a known good date of the right type:

```
IF DATEPART(dw,getdate()) = DATEPART(dw,'20130203')
```